# POST values not appearing in recaptcha

Tags: php, post, recaptcha

I have this page which contains a form. The values are `POST`ed over to the next page(`check_values.php`) which manipulates these values. Now I want to add a captcha. but it requires you to redirect the form to a `verify.php` which seems to clear out the posted variables when i redirect to `check_values.php`. I dont want to use session variables in this case. Are there any other method(s) to accomplish this.

Comment: Ajax? Before submitting the form.

Comment: Dont know ajax :-( @VaibhavDesai
maybe if you could send a sample code...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, POST won't persist after a page request.  You'll have to resend them somehow.

If you want to stick with POST, inside the validate page you could populate a form with the `POST`ed variables, and submit it using a Javascript.  Something like

```
<form id='blah' method='post' action='check_values.php'>
    <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST['var1']; ?>' />
    <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST['var2']; ?>' />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById("blah").submit();
</script>
```

Another option is [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), where you can send a redirect header with POST data.  But this may only be useful for opening a stream, and the redirect could be difficult.

---

Of course, the easy way is just use a redirect header and send the data using GET, as @asprin explains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query strings too

In your `verify.php` page, add a query string to the location i.e.,

```
header('Location: check_values.php?captcha='.$postedValue.'');
```

Then in `check_values.php`, you can use `$_GET` to capture that value.

```
$value = $_GET['captcha'];
```

But make sure you sanitize all data coming from the query string

Comment: found an amazing answer...
http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/setup-user-friendly-captcha-jqueryphp/

Answer (score 0):

The following works perfectly
http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/setup-user-friendly-captcha-jqueryphp/